# Libgdx - Gradle Android debuggable

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, libgdx

I would like to make my app debuggable.

When I deploy to my nexus 5x I get this error:

> Error running AndroidLauncher: Cannot debug application from module android on device lge-nexus_5x-(code here). This application does not have the debuggable attribute enabled in its manifest. If you have manually set it in the manifest, then remove it and let the IDE automatically assign it. If you are using Gradle, make sure that your current variant is debuggable.

If I add the debuggable="true" attribute to the android tag in my manifest it works.

But I'm forgetful, so I'd rather do it the proper way with gradle.

I've tried to add a lot of the things I've found on the internet to both my Android module build.gradle, and my project's root level build.gradle.

All to no avail.

What should work?

Thanks,
  Chase

On an tangent, I also tried running my HTML module using the instructions from their site, and it says it's failing because I'm using java 1.7 features but the gradle source is 1.6.  I've also tried googling that to no avail. I was adding some lines like this:

```
sourceCompatibility 1.7
targetCompatibility 1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use build types (Build Variants) in your android gradle file:

`project/android/build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        minifyEnabled true
        pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.AndroidKey
    }
}
```

* There is some proguard stuff and signing config you might not need. Just remove from the release build variant.

You don't need any other configuration in other files. You can see the full source I used in my project [here](https://github.com/viniciuspjardim/colorbeans/blob/master/android/build.gradle).

If you are using Android Studio you can change between your build variants here:

[image: Choose Build Variant]

When you run the project if `release` is selected it will install the **non** debugable apk in your device. Otherwise, if `debug` is selected it will install the debugable apk. Both can be installed at the same time. It will show the app twice in your device.

The problem is that it should be debugable by default. You could remove the `debuggable true` line and the `debug` build variant should still be debugable.

If it does not work paste your manifest and your build.gradle files here so we can see what is going on.

You can look all theses files in my [project](https://github.com/viniciuspjardim/colorbeans). It is also a libGDX project, but it don't have the HTML module.

The [Build Variant docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) might be helpful.